# Strange expansion of a macro inside an environment

Tags: macros, environments, expansion, fp

I'm, I should confess, a total newbie. I'm trying to generate invoices with LaTeX, so I'm using the fp package.

But the strange thing is that calculations occur many times when they should only occur once per product. Here's my LaTeX file, below, can you please help me understand why it's behaving like this? And help me improve it?

The two important pieces of it are probably the environment `invoice` and the macro `product`. For each product I multiply the unit price times the quantity, get that amount and add it to the total amount of the invoice called `TotalHT`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fltpoint}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\RequirePackage{numprint}

% - Page and Headers Style {{{
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headheight}{51pt}
\lhead{\nous}
%\rhead{\nous}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.125mm}
% - }}}

% - New Commands {{{

\def\TotalHT{0}

% set standard decimal position (numprint package)
\nprounddigits{2}

\newcommand{\nous}{
    \small{
        \textsf{%
            \textsc{My Company}\\
            My address\\
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\client}[1]{%
    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \small{\textsf {#1}}
    \end{flushright}
}

\newcommand{\numero}[2]{%
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \begin{center}
        \Huge{\textbf{Facture n° #1}}\\
        \textsf{\small{Du #2}}
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\firstth}[1]{
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{#1}
}

\newenvironment{invoice}{%
    \ignorespaces
    \small
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|r|c|r|}
    \hline
    \firstth{Designation} & Unit Price. & Qty. & Amount\\
    \hline
}%
{%
    \endtabularx%
}

\newcommand{\product}[3]{%
    \FPround\p{#2}{2} 
    \FPeval\m{\p * #3}
    \FPround\m\m{2}
    \FPadd\TotalHT\TotalHT\m
    \global\let\TotalHT\TotalHT
    \message{t \TotalHT  prod #1}
    #1 & 
    \FPround{\p}{#2}{2}\numprint\p &
    #3 &
    \FPround\p{#2}{2} 
    \FPeval\m{\p * #3}
    \numprint\m\\ 
    \hline
}


\newcommand{\totalttc}{
    \FPround\TotalHT\TotalHT{2}
    & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{Total TTC}} & \numprint\TotalHT \\
    \cline{2-4}
}

\newcommand{\enlettres}[1]{
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \textsf{Arrêter la présente facture à la somme de \textbf{#1}.}
}

% - }}}

\begin{document}
\numero{01/2010}{17/03/2010}

\client{
    My Client Sarl.\\
    His address\\
    His phone
}

\begin{invoice}
    \product{product One}{1000.00}{1}
    \product{product Two}{2000}{1}
    \product{product Three}{3000.00}{1}
    \product{Product Four}{5000.00}{1}
    \totalttc
\end{invoice}

\enlettres{Cent dix-sept milles cinq cents euros et zéro centimes}
\end{document}
```

Whenever I run this through pdflatex, I have the message `\message{t \TotalHT  prod #1}` appear more than once for each product. But then again, in the table that's generated in the PDF I have exactly one row per product, but the total is wrong.

Thanks a lot for helping me understand this!

P.S. three brackets in comments like  `% - }}}` and `% - New Commands {{{` are just here for folding in vim

Answer (score 4):

As Mathew said as well the `tabularx` is the culprit. I also did some minor changes
to the way you used the `fp` package. Below code works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\gdef\TotalHT{0}
\newcommand{\product}[3]{%
  #1  &#2   &#3  &\FPmul\temp{#2}{#3}\FPround\temp{\temp}{2}\temp 
%% Totalize
\FPadd\total{\TotalHT}{\temp}
\FPround\total{\total}{2}
\global\let\TotalHT\total
\\ }
\newcommand{\totalttc}{
   \TotalHT  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
    \product{product One}{1000.00}{1}
    \product{product Two}{2000}{1}
    \product{product Three}{3000.00}{1}
    \product{Product Four}{5000.00}{1}
    \product{Product Four}{5000.00}{1}
    &&& Total \totalttc
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey! That's great! I was wondering how to optimize that very part in fact!

Comment: @sam thanks! You can simply turn the tabular into an environment, which I skipped for clarity. I would also rename the `product` to `addRow` it makes more sense. Your example is a great looking document though. Also consider using `longtable` rather than `tabular`, if you are going to have long invoices.

Comment: Thank _you_ @Yiannis! In fact, I translated in a hurry this doc from French, where "product" was "produit" and "invoice" was "facture". I'm working on a draft so that I'll be able to create a new class and then use that cls in every invoice I typeset "cleanly" -I wonder even if cleanly is an english word ;)

Comment: @sam: Vous avez raison; "cleanly" est un vrai mot anglais.

Comment: Mille mercis encore, Matthew! :) -- I browsed this site and many of you seem so professional and the kind of people who do know their stuff. Where did you guys learn TeX? Online? Do you have some good hints for a newbie like me? I'd love to be more fluent with it, since I spend most of my time in the CLI and would love to share that passion with people like you!

Answer (score 2):

The [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment that you are using to typeset the table is evaluating the table contents three times before setting it once.  This is probably to help it do its calculations.

You can avoid this issue by using a `tabular` environment instead:

```
\newenvironment{invoice}{%
    \ignorespaces
    \small
    \tabular{|p{0.5\textwidth}|r|c|r|}
    \hline
    \firstth{Designation} & Unit Price. & Qty. & Amount\\
    \hline
}%
{%
    \endtabular%
}
```

Not quite as pretty as `tabularx` but gets the job done.

If you want `tabularx` and don't mind repeating the calculations, just make sure you initialize:

```
\newenvironment{invoice}{%
    \ignorespaces
    \small
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|r|c|r|}
    \hline
    \firstth{Designation} & Unit Price. & Qty. & Amount\\
    \hline
    \def\TotalHT{0}
    \global\let\TotalHT\TotalHT
}%
{%
    \endtabularx%
}
```

Yet another way might be to store the order in a list data structure and total it separately from setting the table.  But I suspect this is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: PS Welcome to TeX.SE! You will get a quicker answer if you trim down your question and sample document to the smallest possible example of the odd behavior.  Otherwise answerers may find it overwhelming.

Comment: Thank you so much @Matthew and @Yiannis! Your explanations and suggestions are great! @Matthew thanks also for the advice about TeX.SE! I feel that this community is really a warm one (and sorry for my poor english)